# matrices whose entries sum to zero

Tags: matrix-theory, matrices

Let $A$ be a non-singular matrix and let $s(A)$ be the sum of its entries. Under which conditions can it be assured that $s(A) \neq 0$?

if you like, you can assume that $A$ is symmetric.

Here is an example with $s(A)=0$:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3  \\\\ 2 & -4 & -1\\\\  3 & -1 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Why did you choose a symmetric example?

Comment: Because I am mostly interested in the symmetric case. But the question strikes me as interesting in general.

Comment: I don't think this is a well stated question.


Comment: Why not, if I may ask?

Comment: For one thing, they are all singular. Why do you study these matrices, and what kind of properties are you interested in? See http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask .

Comment: Well, they are not necessarily singular!! 

If you look at my example, you'll that it's determinant is 63. 

As for why I study them - I cam up against an expression of the form $j^{T}R^{-1}j$ in my work, where $R$ is some particular matrix related to signless Laplacians and I need to eliminate the case that this quantity is zero. I thought originally, as you did, that nonsigularity precludes zero sum,

I can analyze my own very special $R$ but I'm curious if there is something general to be said here - and this is what mathematics is about in the final analysis, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, I made a stupid mistake with the singularity. Anyway, you should edit your motivation into the question, and you should really make the question more focused and specific. Vague questions of the form “what is known about X” are rather frowned upon here.

Comment: Yes, I see that frowning is a common expression here. :(

Comment: Anyway, I edited the question. Is this form more acceptable? Thanks.

Comment: The entry sum is $e Ae^t$, where $e=(1,1,\dots, 1)$. Does this help?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. I sorta know that ;)

Comment: In my opinion the edited version (in combination with the comment) is considerable better then orig. My feeling would be that there cannot be said (too) much, since the condition does not feel that restricitive and natural (eg not being compatible with multiplication). But perhaps there is something, which then I would find quite interesting to know. So, perhaps let us leave this edited version open and around. If somebody has something substantial to say it is interesting, if not the question will sink into the depth of MO quickly, open or closed regardless.   

Comment: Yes, never mind the update. Sorry. I'll remove it.

I was just excited about the Khinchin inequality. Sometimes I get too excited :(

Comment: Trivial sufficient conditions are easy to find: say if $e$ is an eigenvector, then clearly the sum is not zero. I guess you are searching for necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: Non-trivial sufficient conditions will also do :)

Comment:  Permuting all the entries of the matrix has no effect on the condition $s(A)\ne0$. Are there conditions on a matrix which remain invariant under all permutations of its entries?. Perhaps this is better viewed as a question on  $\mathbf{R^m}$ where
$m$ happens to be a square number.

On the other hand (from a computational perspective), the condition $S(A)\ne0$ itself is an uncomplicated easy-to-verify condition that I don't see why one needs another condition that would imply this?



Comment: @P Vanchinathan: originally, the matrix in question was actually the inverse of another matrix, and so not available explicitly. 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that, as quid suggested, very little can be said, at least if we want to say something invariant under rotations of coordinates.  Specifically, the following are equivalent for a symmetric real matrix $M$:

(1) There is an orthogonal matrix $T$ such that $T^{-1}MT$ has entries summing to 0.

(2) The eigenvalues of $M$ do not all have the same sign.

To see this, begin with F. Ladisch's comment that the sum of the entries of $M$ is $eMe^t$, where $e$ is the all-ones vector.  It follows that (1) is equivalent to the existence of some non-zero vector $v$ with $vMv^t=0$, as we can use $T$ to rotate a scalar multiple of $e$ to $v$. Clearly no such $v$ can exist if the quadratic form defined by $M$ is strictly positive definite or strictly negative definite, i.e., if all the eigenvalues have the same sign.  Conversely, if there is an eigenvector $x$ with positive eigenvalue $\lambda$ and there is another eigenvector $y$ with negative eigenvalue $-\mu$, and if we normalize $x$ and $y$ to be unit vectors, then, since $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, $v=\sqrt\mu x+\sqrt\lambda y$ does the job.

Comment: Very nice! <<>>

Answer (score 0):

If we are allowing coordinate transformations then a necessary condition is that $0\not\in FOV(A)$.

Comment: FOV?${}{}{}{}{}$